# Reading formatting data from file

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() throws Exception{
        setSize(400, 240);
        JTextPane topPanel = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc;
        doc=topPanel.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        editor.setEditorKit(rtf);
        topPanel.add(editor);
        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("test.rtf");
        FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("test2.rtf");
        keyWord.getAttribute(fi);
        rtf.read(fi, editor.getDocument(), 0);
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Test\ntest2", keyWord);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rtf.write(fo, doc, 0, 0);
        fo.close();
        fi.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Main mainFrame = new Main();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have a question about getting formatting data. I would like to get formatting date from file "test.rtf" to object "keyWord", because I would like to make new string with the same formatting data and save it to "test2.rtf". How to do it?

Comment: What is the concrete problem?

Comment: I can't getting data format from file, because I want use this format to new String.

Comment: Do you want to copy the text from `test.rtf` to `test2.rtf` via the `keyWord` object? I'm not understanding your problem.

Comment: I want to 'paste' formatted text from test.rtf to test2.rtf or make some changes like increasing font size in whole text

Comment: What does the content of test.rtf look like?  Is the entire contents of the document a formatted date?  If so, what format is it in?  Have you used the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes before?

Comment: No, it is only colorful text

Comment: Alright, I understood your problem. I'll try to do it myself and post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example a `List<String>` is being copied to a `JTextPane` which has a `SimpleAttributeSet` attached to it.

```
public class Stackoverflow 
{       
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws HeadlessException
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stackoverflow | Question");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
        {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(1280, 720);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            final SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.RED);
            final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
            pane.setPreferredSize(frame.getContentPane().getSize());
            final StyledDocument document = pane.getStyledDocument();
            try 
            {
                int length = 0;
                for (String string : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.rtf")) 
                {
                    document.insertString(length, string, set);
                    length += string.length();
                }
            } 
            catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) 
            {
                badLocationException.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        });
    }
}
```